# VS2013 Code Coverage

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

I have the following Test:

```
[Test]
public void GrantResourceOwnerCredentials_NullClientID_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
    {   
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() =>{ new ApplicationOAuthProvider(null,null); }); 

    }
```

The test passed, but when i run code coverage, it highlights

`new ApplicationOAuthProvider(null,null);`

as "Coverage Partially Touched Area".

How do i fix that?

By the way, I am new to Unit Testing/Code Coverage so go easy on me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you see a result of "Partially touched", what that means is that there are multiple code paths that can be traversed through a method (such as through an `if` block, a null check, etc.), and only one path was executed by your tests.

For example, if you had the following method:

```
public string IsThisEvenOrOdd(int number)
{
  return (number % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd";
}
```

And you write the following unit test:

```
public string IsThisEvenOrOdd_PositiveEvenNumber_ReturnsEven()
{
    var number = 2;
    var expected = "Even";

    var actual = IsThisEvenOrOdd(number);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

If you run that test, it should succeed. However, it only tests one path - the "Even" path. You'll need to write at least one other test to test the "Odd" result before that method will show up as "fully covered" by MSTest.